# Parsing result URL from Facebook request API properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I have written the following code which sends a predefined GraphAPI object to another Facebook user in my iOS app. This works well.

```
-(void)FacebookSendObjectWithIdentifier: (NSString *)objectIdentifier withObjectName:(NSString *)objectName withMessage:(NSString *)message withTitle:(NSString *)title withActionType:(NSString *)actionType runOnComplete:(void (^)(NSDictionary* request))completionBlock{

NSMutableDictionary* params =   [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

                                 // Optional parameter for sending request directly to user
                                 // with UID. If not specified, the MFS will be invoked
                                 //@"RECIPIENT_USER_ID", @"to",

                                 // Give the action object request information
                                 actionType, @"action_type",
                                 objectIdentifier, @"object_id",
                                 nil];

[FBWebDialogs
 presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
 message:message
 title:title
 parameters:params
 handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
         // Error launching the dialog or sending the request.
         NSLog(@"Error sending %@ request.", objectName);
     } else {
         if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
             // User clicked the "x" icon
             NSLog(@"User canceled %@ request.", objectName);
         } else {
             // Handle the send request callback
             NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];

             if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"request"]) {
                 // User clicked the Cancel button
                 NSLog(@"User canceled %@ request.", objectName);
             } else {
                 // User clicked the Send button
                 NSString *requestID = [urlParams valueForKey:@"request"];
                 NSLog(@"%@ request sent, request id: %@", objectName, requestID);

                 if (completionBlock)
                     completionBlock(urlParams);
             }
         }
     }
 }];
}
```

[self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]]; is implemented throughout several Facebook documentation pages as follows:

```
- (NSDictionary*)parseURLParams:(NSString *)query {
NSArray *pairs = [query componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (NSString *pair in pairs) {
    NSArray *kv = [pair componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
    NSString *val =
    [kv[1] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    params[kv[0]] = val;
}
return params;
}
```

On return, the completion block parses the returned urlParams and saves them to our database to reference the object sent via Facebook. However, this should return a "request" parameter which holds the request ID, and an array, "to" which holds the Facebook IDs of the people the object was sent to. Instead, this returns two fields in the url, "request" which acts fine, and "to[0]" instead of "to" as an NSString instead of NSArray, since the method provided above parses the url parameters as strings rather than corresponding objects, which turns the array "to" into a "to[0]" NSString.

I am looking for either a better solution to parse the returned response URL from Facebook or a better way to send an object through Facebook's API. Preferablly the first option as this is the only step missing for the implementation to be complete.

Thank you.